# Having problem with all the browsers whilw using on ubuntu 22.04. (especially while attaching the files )

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome, downloads

Recently I updated the system using `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. Simultaneously all the browsers are not working properly. The main problem  is while attaching the files or uploading a file or downloading a file, when I click the browse button or attachment button, the web browser hangs and then I can not click on anywhere in the browser. In the end I need to quit the browser and then reopen it. I have been struggling to resolve this issue for many weeks.

[image: If you observe the Attach files symbol in the image]